# В чём отличия доступа до свойства через точку и через []?

Tags: javascript

Почему доступ до свойства объекта через точку не работает? А только через []?

```js
var obj = {
    name: "Wee Gillis",
    age: 19,
    job: "developer"
};



for (key in obj) {
    console.log(obj.key);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если быть точнее, то `obj.key` не "не работает", а возвращает `undefined`.

Это связано с тем, что `obj.key` обозначает доступ к конкретному свойству объекта с названием `"key"` - эквивалентно `obj["key"]` - вне зависимости от значения переменной `key`.

А `obj[key]` (с квадратными скобками и без кавычек) обращается к свойству объекта, чье название хранится в переменной `key`.

Так должно быть понятнее:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Wee Gillis",
    age: 19,
    job: "developer",
    key: 12345 // <-- поле с названием "key"
};    

for (key in obj) { // key принимает значения 'name', 'age', 'job', 'key'
    console.log(obj.key); // <-- всегда выводит 12345
    console.log(key + " - " + obj[key]); // <-- выводит 'name - Wee Gillis', 'age - 19', 'job - developer', 'key - 12345'
}
```

Если бы obj.key работал как вы предполагаете, то для доступа к конкретному полю - например "name" - пришлось бы писать не `obj.name`, а `obj["name"]` - лишние две пары кавычек/скобок. А это очень частая операция.

Answer (score 1):

By design. Так сделано. Запись `obj.key` говорит о доступе к полю `key`. В вашем случае поля `key` у объекта нет, а переменная `key` содержит имя этого поля. В `Javascript` к имени поля объекта можно обратиться через оператор `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что в цикле for...in переменная key принимает строковое значение, равное названию ключа объекта, т.е. грубо говоря получаем подобную картину

```
var param = "name",
obj = {name: "someName", age: 12};
console.log(obj.param);    //undefined
console.log(obj[param]);    //someName
```